# Change lost password url to a mailto URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, functions, filters

can you help me, how can I change the lost password link to an email action with specified subject?
I found that in the functions.php I can add a new filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url',  'my_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
function my_lostpassword_url() {
    return site_url('/password-reset/');
}
```

But I dont know how can I implement the mailto action instead of the new url. Can you help me?

Comment: A mailto action is just a URL that starts with `mailto:` instead of `http:` or `https:`, the specifics of how a `mailto` URL is formatted or built though isn't a WordPress problem but a general HTML question

Comment: a quick google of "mailto url" gives this and a tonne of others https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-create-a-mailto-link-3466469, `<a href="mailto:webdesign@example.com">Send me an email</a>`

Comment: :-) I know what is a mailto action, but my question was how can I implement into the code, what I wrote above. Please listen to my question before giving an unnecessarily wrong answer. Thank you!

Comment: These aren't answers, they're comments, answers will appear underneath with voting controls and their own comments. Note that any answer you get will require basic programming knowledge, it won't be a copy paste solution. Can you expand on what's missing that you don't understand or have? Is the code above code that you wrote? How familiar are you with filters

Comment: So, I have a webpage, where I'd like to control the lost passwords. I disabled earlier the reset password option under WP. I searched and found an answer in this forum, where somebody want the change the default lost password page url. This is the code about I wrote. I don't want another page with another url for lost password, but if somebody lost his password then write me an e-mail with subject lost password. If I write it in a html page then it is a simple ```<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=Mail from Our Site">Email Us</a>```

Comment: But I'm not an expert under php and WP functions.php file, where are the filter of lostpassword url, contains this php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you're running PHP 5.3 or above.

Use the filter code below in-place of your code that you quoted above. Then simply update the variables provided so that it's sending to the correct email address and with the particular subject you'd like.

```php
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', function () {
    $email_to = 'someone@yoursite.com';
    $email_subject =  'Help I lost my password';
    return sprintf( 'mailto:%s?subject=%s', $email_to, $email_subject );
}, 100, 0 );
```

**Note**: You cannot change the anchor text "Lost Password" that is used in the link.

Comment: Thank you very much!